# Как читать данные из сокета с помощью QDataStream?

Tags: macos, c, qt

Сервер написан на Си и посылает сообщение клиенту:

```
char *ch = "text";
...
send(i32ConnectFD, ch, strlen(ch), 0);
```

Клиент написан на Qt и если читать данные таким образом:

```
connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(read()));
...
void Client::read() {
   QString string(tcpSocket.readAll());
   qDebug() << string
}
```

то все работает и текст "text" выводит в qDebug.
Но как быть, если я хочу использовать потоки QDataStream, для того чтобы читать данные блоками?
Пытался так:

```
void Client::read() {
   QDataStream dataStream(tcpSocket);
   QString string;
   dataStream >> string;
   qDebug() << string;
}
```

в итоге я получил пустоту:

> ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        QTcpSocket* m_pTcpSocket;
        quint16     m_nNextBlockSize;
        QDataStream in(m_pTcpSocket);
        in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_5);
        for (;;) {
            if (!m_nNextBlockSize) {
                if (m_pTcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16)) {
                    break;
                }
                in >> m_nNextBlockSize;
            }

            if (m_pTcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < m_nNextBlockSize) {
                break;
            }
            QString ID;
            QString IDr;
            QString str;
            in >> ID >> IDr >> str;
```

Подробнее можно почитать здесь: http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4582272

Comment: Я не совсем могу понять вот эту строку: ` if (m_pTcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16)) `тут говориться о том что первые два байта это размер блока? Т.е. мне надо от сервера сначала вперед прислать размер строки, а потом уже саму строку?

Comment: Да. Если бы сервер был на QT, то отправка была примерно так:

    QByteArray  arrBlock;
    QDataStream out(&arrBlock, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_5);
    out << quint16(0) << str;

    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << quint16(arrBlock.size() - sizeof(quint16));

    pSocket->write(arrBlock);

Comment: Но у меня сервер на чистом Си надо. Думаю вина именно в нем. Надо как-то и на сервера блоком отправлять.
P.S. Кстати, как ты код вставил в комментариях?

Comment: На чем написан сервер - не имеет значения. Значение имеет сам протокол. У Вас строки отправляются без указания длины или символа конца. И как их потом получать - непонятно. Более того, функция send в некоторых случаях может отправить не все данные, а только часть. У Вас проверки похоже нет.

Рекомендую вначале определиться с протоколом сервера, а потом забыть о QDataStream и делать ручками. Либо писать сервер с использованием Qt и QDataStream.